# Joomla on Ubuntu 12.04 Warning: Failed to move file! error

Tags: 12.04, joomla

I am trying to install a template that I have downloaded online and it is giving me an error of Warning: Failed to move file! .. How do I resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a file permission problem.  Your template folder or the whole joomla folder on the server appears to not be setup to allow the browser agent to change the folders.  Depending on what server you're using (Windows based IIS or Unix based Apache), [this article](http://docs.joomla.org/What_are_the_recommended_file_and_directory_permissions%3F) may help or at least point you in the right direction.

You can check the permissions on a folder or file by locating the folder or file on the server (through FTP if on a remote server or directly if on a local server), right-click, select properties, and the permissions/security tab.  You may have the option to select permissions from a list or to enter the numeric code of a permission.

In the article above, the numbers 755 and 644 are number codes for file permissions.  See [this article](http://www.elated.com/articles/understanding-permissions/) for an overview of Unix/Linux file/folder permissions.  It explains the number codes.